# Certificate chain is broken

Tags: certificate-authority

I'm trying to create a certificate chain using bouncy castle.

First I create a CA cert:

```
public static void CreateCertificateAuthorityCertificate(string commonNameValue, [CanBeNull] out AsymmetricKeyParameter caPrivateKey, out X509Certificate2 caCert)
    {
        const int keyStrength = 2048;

        var random = GetSeededSecureRandom();

        // The Certificate Generator
        X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

        // Serial Number
        BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
        certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

        // Issuer and Subject Name
        X509Name subjectDN = new X509Name("CN=" + commonNameValue);
        X509Name issuerDN = subjectDN;
        certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
        certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

        // Valid For
        DateTime notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-7);
        DateTime notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(2);

        certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
        certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

        // Subject Public Key
        var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
        var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
        var subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

        certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

        // Generating the Certificate
        var issuerKeyPair = subjectKeyPair;
        ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA512WITHRSA", issuerKeyPair.Private, random);

        // selfsign certificate
        var certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);

        caPrivateKey = issuerKeyPair.Private;
        caCert = new X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());
    }
```

Then, I use the following code twice.

The first time, I generate a "Server Certificate" that is going to be used to generate client certificates. In this case I use the private key of the CA cert and isClientCertificate set to false.

Then, I use the same code to generate the "Client Certificate", this time using the private key of the "Server Certificate" and isClientCertificate set to true.

```
public static X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedCertificateBasedOnPrivateKey(string commonNameValue, X509Certificate2 issuerCertificate, AsymmetricKeyParameter issuerPrivKey, bool isClientCertificate, int yearsUntilExpiration)
    {
        const int keyStrength = 2048;

        // Generating Random Numbers
        var random = GetSeededSecureRandom();
        ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA512WITHRSA", issuerPrivKey, random);

        // The Certificate Generator
        X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

        if (isClientCertificate)
        {
            certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage.Id, true, new ExtendedKeyUsage(KeyPurposeID.IdKPClientAuth));
        }
        else
        {
            certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier.Id, true, 
                new X509KeyUsage(X509KeyUsage.KeyCertSign));
        }

        // Serial Number
        BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
        certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

        // Issuer and Subject Name
        var readCertificate = new X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(issuerCertificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert));
        X509Name subjectDN = new X509Name("CN=" + commonNameValue);
        certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(readCertificate.SubjectDN);
        certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

        // Valid For
        DateTime notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-7);
        DateTime notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(yearsUntilExpiration);
        certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
        certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

        // Subject Public Key
        var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
        var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
        var subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

        certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

        X509Certificate certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);
        var store = new Pkcs12Store();
        string friendlyName = certificate.SubjectDN.ToString();
        var certificateEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(certificate);
        store.SetCertificateEntry(friendlyName, certificateEntry);
        store.SetKeyEntry(friendlyName, new AsymmetricKeyEntry(subjectKeyPair.Private), new[] { certificateEntry });
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        store.Save(stream, new char[0], random);
        var convertedCertificate =
            new X509Certificate2(
                stream.ToArray(), (string)null,
                X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        stream.Position = 0;

        return convertedCertificate;
    }
```

The CA and Server certs look good, including a valid chain.

[image]

My problem is with the client certificate chain.

There is a yellow warning on the "Server Certificate" (in the screenshot it's called CN=iftah-pc), it says: This certification authority is not allowed to issue certificates or cannot be used as an end-entity certificate.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I used OpenSSL to extract the contents of the certificate, I get:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            45:67:f2:4b:9a:19:ff:f7
    Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = IFTAH-PC.ravendb.ca
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep  4 00:00:00 2017 GMT
            Not After : Sep  4 00:00:00 2022 GMT
        Subject: CN = iftah-pc
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b4:d1:b9:21:30:fe:d3:25:ec:f5:7d:c0:70:42:
                    ac:8a:eb:4d:88:5a:ee:8a:a4:c3:93:a8:84:47:bc:
                    ad:56:0a:c4:d9:4a:4f:2d:4b:a1:35:37:ed:24:d9:
                    c1:20:40:c3:4a:3f:59:87:8c:da:00:88:52:24:da:
                    bf:59:bd:48:47:f7:f0:30:ad:87:ec:c6:33:33:8d:
                    b6:a8:f7:5e:94:64:ff:16:02:7d:f2:7c:b1:7d:a3:
                    14:0b:5a:13:50:1a:f7:11:02:40:c6:4f:32:a7:a8:
                    87:a2:e1:73:e9:23:19:1f:5f:53:87:d4:79:5f:20:
                    d8:d9:f9:cd:a3:c6:3f:44:ee:56:d7:2f:a4:f7:6d:
                    58:6e:5f:40:80:40:26:e2:31:ff:d4:5b:57:03:77:
                    f4:e0:3f:48:26:91:a4:cf:11:d7:c9:54:d1:82:8b:
                    16:4b:09:92:7e:3a:ad:75:48:ba:7b:9b:48:07:45:
                    37:20:2a:33:cc:5d:70:b2:62:60:e7:38:ea:d2:09:
                    2f:6f:59:b6:94:f0:f8:c9:fb:7a:53:5f:bb:0b:d8:
                    16:c0:04:7e:06:1d:60:94:50:ae:d3:49:01:35:0d:
                    29:f7:3e:cf:67:7b:57:6d:d3:76:86:44:25:6a:c7:
                    f5:f0:69:34:e8:f3:33:93:d2:32:b5:92:2f:55:96:
                    53:73
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption
         59:d8:27:48:62:05:24:cc:1d:c8:b5:23:c1:ee:64:c8:f3:2a:
         f1:ee:67:fb:77:23:ec:a4:80:a3:30:a9:44:b4:4b:36:88:7c:
         cf:65:ac:e7:5e:44:63:ba:a3:01:c2:6f:d3:ea:c9:da:31:72:
         0b:57:87:07:58:0e:ce:c7:ad:df:5b:ff:02:f6:d4:b0:65:8f:
         f7:28:0f:5b:4d:32:75:3b:93:ae:0b:3a:13:c6:29:0f:d2:20:
         a8:3e:80:06:13:f4:ef:8d:af:32:25:ee:79:8a:98:3f:63:3f:
         b8:35:cb:a9:a2:c2:a2:73:aa:ea:c1:e4:c2:02:2d:0a:42:42:
         27:c7:78:2b:3e:c8:a1:89:7c:40:76:75:15:4d:b8:45:a8:06:
         6f:85:d0:fd:2c:8c:ae:e4:27:90:0f:56:a6:17:f0:16:e3:5b:
         38:62:af:01:d0:e3:72:ee:17:ac:8c:fe:91:fe:37:02:41:c3:
         5b:51:26:5d:59:d6:ab:fb:54:6d:05:d3:3c:3c:c7:94:b3:8e:
         3d:57:38:3a:cf:35:c5:ac:93:3d:62:39:85:1d:f7:eb:97:54:
         b1:b5:03:f1:3d:38:b8:d5:ae:0e:3e:b1:ec:e2:b3:0c:a5:95:
         58:58:2d:ba:20:df:a3:35:86:f3:f0:94:9e:13:8e:0c:70:92:
         e3:ba:e5:c4
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

As far as I can see, I have done things right, in particular: `X509v3 Key Usage: critical Certificate Sign, CRL Sign` is set properly.

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you set the `keyCertSign` flag on the intermediate CA's cert? (Related question: SecSE, 2017-03-02, [*Intermediate certificate not allowed to issue certificates?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152796/intermediate-certificate-not-allowed-to-issue-certificates).)

Comment: Yes, added an extension with X509KeyUsage.KeyCertSign

Comment: I'm on the fence about moving this to StackOverflow. Is it more of a programming question, or more of a security theory question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it myself, was missing a basic constraint.

`certificateGenerator.AddExtension( X509Extensions.BasicConstraints.Id, true,` [`new BasicConstraints(3)`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.3/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/BasicConstraints.html#BasicConstraints(int))`);`

And using openssl we can see that a constraint was added `CA:TRUE`

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        cf:06:3a:b1:ce:8d:98:f4
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C = GB, ST = England, O = Alice Ltd
    Validity
        Not Before: Sep 11 12:53:06 2017 GMT
        Not After : Sep  6 12:53:06 2037 GMT
    Subject: C = GB, ST = England, O = Alice Ltd
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            Public-Key: (4096 bit)
            Modulus:
                00:dc:c5:c9:d3:15:5c:62:d5:2c:9d:e7:74:31:e8:
                96:db:08:c2:4d:3b:68:22:5a:df:e5:56:ef:ad:3a:
                0f:7d:82:6a:ab:f5:a2:5c:11:76:49:38:d0:3b:9f:
                18:8e:99:09:3d:91:14:6b:1f:32:70:05:bc:33:d5:
                73:8e:53:6e:0d:f0:83:44:9d:5b:96:fa:0f:47:27:
                54:3d:6e:a1:71:25:db:04:9b:e3:f6:58:bc:da:b4:
                e1:f2:43:cb:d1:73:f2:1f:3b:b6:c7:de:10:6b:22:
                ee:55:38:6e:79:ac:7d:83:ff:d2:dd:18:0d:9a:89:
                23:7e:01:7a:08:07:04:9d:65:28:1d:05:5c:de:3e:
                d4:ad:62:e4:85:34:94:56:b0:e0:19:10:f3:90:32:
                37:19:06:2f:ba:81:d1:67:d2:cc:89:4d:1d:dd:cf:
                3d:46:27:28:c9:0d:ee:d1:9e:b1:be:de:00:2b:65:
                46:45:18:d2:45:19:de:b3:e1:a3:7c:5d:1d:24:05:
                79:13:57:24:36:b9:ab:07:68:0c:fa:78:eb:84:ee:
                ea:c8:6b:05:96:9f:af:d6:8b:74:97:6f:8b:55:cc:
                6c:50:22:85:f5:fc:ea:fc:08:b2:fc:d2:23:64:59:
                a1:61:55:ef:fb:be:f0:ad:60:41:62:24:07:bf:31:
                0b:93:1b:ee:02:6d:f3:9f:1e:c6:09:69:70:3a:64:
                c4:5f:c0:5a:b8:a3:21:e1:7d:72:96:75:75:db:b0:
                0d:b5:9a:52:b4:d3:13:0e:a4:22:66:8c:47:09:4d:
                82:c5:97:15:9a:f2:f9:38:e4:38:6d:82:53:ce:76:
                45:8d:32:ef:82:0c:5b:12:ac:0d:9f:74:c6:4c:8f:
                13:7a:05:8f:44:d1:70:e6:41:b7:da:74:28:d3:8b:
                a3:d1:24:42:b7:66:35:62:d1:1d:44:8d:62:da:ce:
                b8:39:fb:29:e7:0f:9b:9d:49:c1:c0:5c:41:22:01:
                9d:4c:4a:74:f4:66:30:12:77:c9:44:f2:af:c6:03:
                d3:1c:a4:3f:bb:52:a8:9e:58:b8:97:a2:b0:ce:54:
                9c:2e:ae:2a:0c:15:97:87:b3:c2:29:a8:59:ba:55:
                a4:98:c0:e7:de:54:9d:68:03:df:87:ee:82:b3:c7:
                21:23:ff:63:b7:a8:39:a6:36:21:7a:50:04:53:7b:
                30:20:5b:a5:f2:4d:c3:a4:f2:30:f9:b2:b9:39:87:
                3a:a7:bf:15:1d:71:ad:15:e0:1c:86:4a:25:06:d4:
                d1:2d:be:82:a1:f1:e2:79:d5:32:ad:a9:05:44:dd:
                c4:9a:83:3f:3c:8c:f1:55:ba:17:81:7c:0a:b6:90:
                e0:21:c9
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            44:3F:CD:D2:03:9D:0B:24:D9:FF:AE:7A:8D:23:8C:63:91:FD:EF:6C
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            keyid:44:3F:CD:D2:03:9D:0B:24:D9:FF:AE:7A:8D:23:8C:63:91:FD:EF:6C

        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
     b9:f6:30:1d:20:e6:19:f5:90:57:95:eb:93:4c:e9:40:ee:b7:
     60:12:83:a5:02:42:b3:c6:51:f5:41:cc:46:b6:c5:40:12:59:
     f7:a2:0b:0e:04:2e:54:f4:55:8e:23:68:f1:2f:f2:a4:80:ea:
     a8:24:45:fc:5a:61:3a:af:96:75:52:e2:fb:f9:28:43:9c:6f:
     0e:2f:08:d9:1f:cc:05:4a:93:40:fe:ab:8b:8d:4b:4f:fe:16:
     b6:89:b4:b6:f2:47:6d:8f:b7:89:71:d1:2f:56:d6:36:0a:7b:
     e0:1e:b3:96:bc:ba:ba:cf:c1:ff:10:45:2d:60:7a:33:11:71:
     84:bd:9e:94:e7:6a:52:8f:2d:e3:6b:b5:23:4c:2e:53:fe:56:
     7e:f1:a0:ba:56:93:65:5a:3c:98:e4:ac:84:e9:ea:4f:fd:4a:
     35:84:f9:d1:82:8c:7f:62:57:85:37:e8:6c:16:b3:0d:8b:08:
     d8:57:e5:e0:d3:b1:91:6d:da:b9:05:e8:2f:2e:34:6a:d6:2a:
     9b:79:1c:4d:0c:a4:56:f1:94:27:58:a5:98:67:c0:91:28:ab:
     96:cf:d0:cd:73:a7:4a:22:5b:f9:97:c0:3b:c7:f7:47:59:60:
     55:7c:70:c5:4c:d0:e8:09:39:91:70:fb:aa:e8:8c:bb:72:66:
     04:7b:15:c1:de:1a:81:42:d7:0e:69:a2:8c:7b:00:c9:2a:be:
     94:0d:a1:ef:6c:40:3c:0b:08:2c:40:32:8f:0e:3b:ec:04:6c:
     a1:d3:3f:21:b1:03:24:c8:86:86:3b:d9:3b:43:11:69:0f:b3:
     d6:0a:6d:a5:f4:36:40:04:41:93:fd:56:ad:ec:68:82:47:9f:
     cb:f5:ad:3b:0e:0a:fc:3e:ad:21:6f:e6:81:fa:56:69:40:d2:
     9e:82:71:1e:a0:f9:8b:a1:82:d9:4d:11:89:85:30:c5:be:e4:
     e2:0d:33:6b:e2:a0:2b:75:4c:df:da:ac:d5:54:4a:fd:bd:06:
     73:4e:85:5b:2c:a7:9e:f2:37:91:2c:e7:07:fb:d7:49:18:3a:
     7f:bc:6a:08:3c:e3:42:c6:c2:58:ec:4a:65:cc:e4:7e:1e:38:
     91:ee:79:cf:23:a9:a1:28:0f:9c:41:ef:64:27:a5:0d:3f:aa:
     0d:40:2c:13:a1:c4:51:6b:c9:a4:4a:b0:57:4d:3a:2e:b0:38:
     a8:5d:f6:94:a6:da:29:20:d2:3f:2c:ba:5c:63:01:a3:77:3f:
     6b:21:f2:01:6a:fe:bf:3b:ff:de:b6:4d:23:d1:3b:08:43:f2:
     c0:97:7a:f4:17:36:71:e7:67:72:9f:c4:61:61:93:9f:33:f8:
     49:f4:b6:99:cf:da:cd:ed
```

[image]

Happy end :)

Comment: And shouldn't there also be a certificate path length constraint of "3" now? Why don't I see that?